# Why is the determiner after the verb in "We were both tired" and "We have both seen the movie"?

Tags: sentence-structure, determiners, syntax

There are two sentences to determiner below:

> 1. We were both tired.

> 2. We have both seen the movie.

What I know is that the determiner is used in front of noun or pronoun, but the sentences of examples show that the determiner is located after verb.

I would like to know reason why the determiner is after verb.

Comment: "Both" is **not** a determiner in either of your examples, but an adjunct in clause structure. It would, however, be a determiner in "Both men were tired".

Answer (score 2):

> We were both tired.

There is no determiner.  "Tired" is an adjective.

But the word "both" can be a determiner:

> Both cats were black, which I took as an omen.

> We have both seen the movie.

Find the determiner.  It is the definite article: **the**.

Comment: Oh dear! "Both" belongs solely to the part of speech 'determinative', though it can have different functions. For example, in "Both men were tired" its function is that of determniner, and in "We were both tired" it's an optional adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ  Right!  This is the usual story about English words: they are complex.

Comment: That's true. Incidentally, notice the slight spelling difference between the part of speech 'determin**ative**' and the function 'determin**er**'.

Comment: I see your point. Good!

Comment: @Billj  according to https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/both?q=both, the part of speech of 'both' is determiner.

Comment: @bak1936 Yes, most dictionaries use the function term 'determiner' instead of the category term 'determinative'. The important thing to grasp here is that in _We were both tired_ "both" functions not as a determiner but as an **adjunct**. By contrast, in _Both men were tired_ it does function as a determiner. Can you see the difference?

Comment: @BillJ thanks for your answer.